# How to add existing local project to a already existing, empty GitHub Repo

Tags: github

I have a existing solution/csproj I am working on and I have not integrated any source control into it.

How can I take this solution, and all of it associated projects and upload that to the empty repo on GitHub

Comment: Take a look at GitHub Tutorial? https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github#about-adding-existing-source-code-to-github